# Differentiability in the hyperbolic plane

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

i have this question:

Let $\mathbb{H}^2$ be the hyperbolic plane and $u:\mathbb{H}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. I would like to understand (the definition or an explanation) what does it mean?:

"$u$ is differentiable almost everywhere with respect to  the Borel measure given by the hyperbolic metric".

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Out of context, this is meaningless. I suspect it is "differentiable almost everywhere with respect to ...."

Comment: almost every where yes i will edit it

Comment: Differentability of a function depends only on the smooth structure of the manifold and not on the Riemannian metric. Hence, differentiability of a function defined on the upper half plane should be understood in the calculus sense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the meaning of almost everywhere depends on the measure.

Comment: @Thomas: In general, yes, but not in this case since Euclidean and hyperbolic measures are absolutely continuous with respect to each other. Ditto for measures defined via Riemannian on a general smooth manifold.